# SQL Maintain Up to Date Count of Related Records in Another Table

Tags: sql-server

I have two related tables. One for article categories and another of articles. I want to maintain a count of the number of articles by category within the "Categories" table. My tables are as follows:

Categories

```
ID | CatName | ArticleCount
1  | Cat1    | 
2  | Cat2    | 
3  | Cat3    |
```

Articles

```
ID | CatID | ArticleName
1  | 1     | Art1
2  | 2     | Art2
3  | 3     | Art3
4  | 1     | Art4
```

Using SQL, how would I have a continuous update of the Categories table when articles are added so that I can maintain an up to date count of the number of articles by category? I envision my Categories table ending up like this given the example data I have provided:

Categories (with ArticleCount automatically updated based on related records in the Articles table)

```
ID | CatName | ArticleCount
1  | Cat1    | 2
2  | Cat2    | 1
3  | Cat3    | 1
```

Comment: It seems to me that continuously updating the count will consume more overhead than just calculating it as needed. I do not believe it would be considered good database practice either. Using count is very efficient since it needs only to traverse the index. I am sure you have a reason for storing the count, so perhaps it would be a good idea to share it with us.

Comment: I need to store the count for display on a Webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can do quite easily is to add ArticleCount as a computed field in the Categories table that points to a UDF that counts the Articles for that category

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_cnt](@CatID   INT)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Articles WHERE CatID = @CatID)
END
GO

CREATE TABLE Categories(
    [Id]        INT,
    [CatName]   [varchar](64),
    [ArticleCount]  AS ([dbo].[fn_cnt]([Id]))
)
GO
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Udf are known to have a negative performance impact, but depending on the volume performance cost will be negligible. If it were me though, I would just select the count wherever I need it. That way I'm not dependant on the database supporting udfs and computed columns.... kiss - keep it straight and simple.